# dc.js and Focus + Context for series charts

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm stuck on getting the focus context to work for dc.js with regards to series line charts. Similar examples are at [DC.js Nasdaq eg](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/) and [another similar DC.js eg](http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2013/08/focus-context-bar-chart-in-javascript/). Both these examples use a linechart for the main graph, linked to the focus graph - a bar chart.

I've inked a JSBin here - http://jsbin.com/cicif/3/edit

The above linked JSBin shows a real time graph with updating data as well as a focus graph below it. When I click on the focus graph and attempt to draw the brush to focus on the real time graph - I get errors pertaining to date time errors as well as rectangle element errors.

What could I be doing wrong here? I'm certain it could be a small detail that I missed - appreciate your insight.